# Symfony2 Sonata Easy Extends bundle - trying to load file that does not exist

Tags: php, symfony

I had a working Symfony2 application that uses several Sonata bundles (core, admin, doctrine-orm-admin, block). I have just pushed some revised code, and did a Composer update. Now, whilst app_dev.php seems to work fine, when I access the production version via app.php, I get an error;

Failed opening required 'vendor/sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle/Sonata/EasyExtendsBundle/SonataEasyExtendsBundle.php'

Looking in the vendors directory, the SonataEasyExtendsBundle.php is there, but it is in vendor/sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle, rather than in vendor/sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle/Sonata/EasyExtendsBundle/

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked appKernel.php to see where that is pointing?

Comment: Yep - everything looked right.

Answer (score 0):

After much puzzling - it turned out to the APC cache. Clearing that resolved the issue. Doh.